# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError debugging, class was not loaded

Tags: java

I have few dependancies (from logback packet) that are linked at the runtime (maven runtime scope). Project compiles, but throws `NoClassDefFoundError` when run (command is `java -jar my_uncool.jar`).

I ran java with  `-verbose:class` option and did not see my logback loaded. I checked the lib folder (`./WEB-INF/lib/`) and have all required `logback's *.jar` files.

What might be the problem?
What are the ways to see the reason of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify the class path of where your jars are located.

```
java -cp "./WEB-INF/lib/*.jar" -jar my_uncool.jar
```

You can add more paths to the classpath as follows.

```
java -cp "./WEB-INF/lib/*.jar;./WEB-INF/lib/another/path/*.jar" -jar my_uncool.jar
```

Comment: No, effect. Same stuff.

Comment: Is there a way to printout debug messages for example, 'Trying to load logback.jar', 'searching in location x', 'searching in location y', to see what java is doing.

Comment: well, the above command assumes that all your jars are the ./WEB-INF/lib directory.  It's a matter of properly configuring your classpath, inorder to get it work.  E.g. if it's ./WEB-INF/lib/path/to/jars/, then you will need to add that as well.

Comment: You could also try java -cp "./WEB-INF/lib/*" -jar my_uncool.jar which should add all the jars including in subfolders.

Comment: @Tom if you want more verbosity and you're on a unix env., then you could always try strace.